# keyboard transmit mode in vt100 terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, vt100

I'm implementing a vt100 terminal emulator in javascript and the vt100 spec (from `man terminfo` and `infocmp`) tells me that `smkx=\E[?1h\E=` is the code to enter key-board transmit mode and `rmkx=\E[?1l\E>` is the code to leave 'key-board transmit' mode. I couldn't really understand what key-board transmit mode is.

From http://vt100.net/dec/ek-vt220-tm-001.pdf,

> **7.4.4.1 Keyboard Transmit Mode** -- The keyboard codes and a few other special codes are transmitted via a serial line output in PORT of the
>   8051. The transmitted signal goes from the 8051 to a driver, through the keyboard cable, monitor and video cable to  the CPU. A UART within
>   the 8051 controls the transmission"

I'm getting these codes while entering into and leaving `vim`, respectively.  Can I safely ignore these codes or do I need to handle them? In the latter case, what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two strings contain two sequences each; they control subtly different things:

The first of these,

```
CSI ? 1h
CSI ? 1l
```

controls DEC private mode number 1, `DECCKM`, cursor key mode. This mode determines whether the four arrow keys (Up, Down, Left, Right) will send SS3 or CSI-prefixed sequences.

The second pair of sequences,

```
ESC =
ESC >
```

are called `DECKPAM`, keypad application mode, and `DECKPNM`, keypad numeric mode. This determines whether the number keypad sends control sequences, or normal numbers (i.e. consider it similar to the Numlock feature).

Answer (score 1):

smkx/rmkx control whether the keypad will transmit numbers or escape code. Also, it is "keypad-transmit-mode" not "keyboard-transmit-mode"