# Terminfo smkx and Application Cursor Keys vs Application keypad

Tags: terminal, tty, xterm, terminfo, termcap

[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) specifies the following key sequences:

```
CSI ? 1 h  → Application Cursor Keys (DECCKM)
CSI ? 1 l  → Normal Cursor Mode (DECOM)
CSI ? 66 h → Application keypad (DECNKM)
CSI ? 66 l → Numeric keypad (DECNKM)
```

and the [Terminfo Source Format](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989799/xcurses/terminfo.html) has the following entry:

```
Variable: keypad_xmit
Capname: smkx
Termcap: ks
Description: Put terminal in "keypad-transmit" mode
```

But the terminfo for xterm actually says `smkx=\E[?1h\E=`, which seems mixed up to me (smkx should affect the keypad, not the cursor keys, right?). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `\E=` at the end of `smkx`.

```
ESC =     Application Keypad (DECKPAM).
ESC >     Normal Keypad (DECKPNM).
```

are listed on the XTerm Control Sequences page as well and you would expect them to affect the keypad.

I found a related question here: [keyboard transmit mode in vt100 terminal emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585131/keyboard-transmit-mode-in-vt100-terminal-emulator).

Comment: I don't know why DECCKM appears in front of it, though.

Answer (score 7):

The line

```
CSI ? 1 h  → Normal Cursor Mode (DECOM)
```

probably should read

```
CSI ? 1 l  → Normal Cursor Keys (DECCKM)
```

There are two escape sequences in each of `smkx` and `rmkx` because these capabilities are used in curses, i.e., for the [`keypad`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html) function.

The manual page for ncurses (like others) does not say so explicitly, but the function applies to all of the *special keys* on the keyboard which have the ability to switch between *normal* and *application* mode.  This is a well-known feature of `smkx` and `rmkx`, as for example in the xterm FAQ [Why can't I use the cursor keys in (whatever) shell?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows).

Special keys on the keyboard may include these (depending on the type of terminal):

- numeric keypad (on the extreme right of a PC keyboard)
- editing keypad (6 keys between the main keyboard and the numeric keyboard)
- cursor keys
- function keys (commonly at the top of a PC keyboard)

The [VT100](http://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html) (which does not have function keys or editing keypad) has separate escape sequences for the other two categories.  In VT220 (emulated by xterm), the editing keypad's normal/application mode is an extension of the VT100 DECCKM, (documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys)).  DEC did not define a corresponding feature for function keys; however if there were some terminal which supported this capability it would probably be used in `smkx` and `rmkx`.